# BroadcastReceiver must provide a public default constructor - Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Ok so I am running a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class SyncServiceBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static string syncStarted = "SyncRuns";

    private readonly PendingOrdersActivity pendingOrdersActivity;

    public SyncServiceBroadcastReceiver(PendingOrdersActivity pendingOrdersActivity)
    {
        this.pendingOrdersActivity = pendingOrdersActivity;
    }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        this.pendingOrdersActivity.RefreshPendingOrdersOnSync();

        Toast.MakeText(context, "Datele se actualizează...", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Each time it hits, I want it to run a method from the activity (method RefreshPendingOrdersOnSync). That's why I've created a constructor which takes in an activity.

In the activity I am registering the BroadcastReceiver, in the OnResume method, by passing in "this":

```
 var filter = new IntentFilter(SyncServiceBroadcastReceiver.syncStarted);
 filter.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
 this.syncServiceBroadcastReceiver = new SyncServiceBroadcastReceiver(this);
 this.RegisterReceiver(this.syncServiceBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

Still, on the Receiver part, it gives the error from the title....
If I add an empty constructor, I suspect it goes through there and this line in the OnReceive breakes, because this.pendingOrdersActivity is null

```
this.pendingOrdersActivity.RefreshPendingOrdersOnSync();
```

I am quite puzzled why

Comment: Did you see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers  You are inheriting the BroadcastReceiver so you inherited class must meet all the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> BroadcastReceiver must provide a public default constructor

The default constructor method is required. Because when registering BroadcastReceiver using `AndroidManifest.xml`, Android uses reflection to instantiate the receiver and it needs a default constructor.

Refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266261/11083277

> If I add an empty constructor, I suspect it goes through there and this line in the OnReceive breakes

I tested a basic demo to test the code, add the default constructor method and the code works fine. The parameterized constructor will be executed. Did you register the receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`? If so, try to do the work in code.

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class CustomReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    private readonly MainActivity activity;

    public CustomReceiver()
    {
    }

    public CustomReceiver(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        activity.method();
    }
}
```

Activity class

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    CustomReceiver receiver;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        receiver = new CustomReceiver(this);
    }
    public void method()
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        RegisterReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("package_name"));
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        UnregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the activity class? I posted the code about the activity class, you could refer to it.

Comment: It is the same. I am broadcasting when a service Runs. Maybe here is the issue? (sorry I am sending an Image it is easier in comments) https://i.imgur.com/2rq5MRQ.png

Comment: basically, I am registering it from the activity (to pass in this) - but I am using it from a Service (I'm broadcasting each time the service runs - every x minutes)

Comment: yep, it's from the service that the receiver is initialized through the empty constructor. But If I broadcast like this:  this.SendBroadcast(new Intent(SyncServiceBroadcastReceiver.syncRuns));       - The app stops responding :((

Comment: The 'this' in the `var broadcastIntent = new Intent(this,typeof(SyncServiceBroadcastReceiver));` is the service instead of the PendingOrdersActivity class. But the context of the  **OnReceive** in the custom receiver class should be type of PendingOrdersActivity class. Try changing the code to `var broadcastIntent = new Intent(typeof(PendingOrdersActivity),typeof(SyncServiceBroadcastReceiver));`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me, I believe I had a particular scenario or something. I have ended renouncing completely to BroadcastReceiver and this implementation.

Comment: Try creating a static intance of the Acitivty class. Then get the instance directly without using a parameter. `[BroadcastReceiver]
public class CustomReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    private readonly MainActivity activity;
    ...
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        activity = MainActivity.instance;
        activity.method();
    }
}`.